# Is $n \choose k$ defined for $n \lt k $?

Tags: combinatorics, definition

I am wondering whether the function $n \choose k$ is defined for $n \lt k$, or if we assume otherwise. If so, what would be the contexts in which we would want to compute $n \choose k$ where $n \lt k$?

Comment: Your question seems to have already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527831/is-n-choose-k-defined-when-k-0-what-about-n-k?rq=1)

Comment: How would you define the factorial of a negative number, like $(-1)!$?

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n<k$ $$\binom{n}{k}=0$$